# Order char type temporary column as integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a query that would show sales for each week for two years. So I want to compare weeks with different year. I get such results (`week` is the number of week within that year, like first week, second week of 2010):

```
week|year|price
1   |2010|5
1   |2011|10
2   |2010|7
2   |2011|13
```

Everything would be ok, but when I try to show results in graph, it counts both first weeks and so on as one and puts it in one field. So in graph I see that first weeks sales are 15, and seconds weeks 20.
So I then I tried to combine week column with another column to separate same week number for different year.

```
SELECT
  min(so.id) as id,
  date_part('week',  so.date_order) || ' ' ||
  CASE
    WHEN
      so.date_order >='2010-01-01' and so.date_order <= '2010-12-31'
    THEN
      '2010'
    WHEN
      so.date_order >='2010-01-01' and so.date_order <= '2011-12-31'
    THEN
      '2011'
  END as week,
  date_part('year',  so.date_order) as year,
  count(*) as amount,
  sum(sol.price_unit) as price
FROM
  sale_order as so, 
  sale_order_line as sol
WHERE
  sol.order_id=so.id and
  so.date_order >= '2010-01-01' and so.date_order <= '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY
  week,
  year
```

But then column week is sorted as char type and I get results in such order:

```
week     |year|sales
1 - 2010 |2010|5
1 - 2011 |2011|10
10 - 2010|2010|15
11 - 2011|2011|12
2  - 2010|2010|7
2  - 2011|2011|13
```

If I try to `ORDER BY to_number(week, text(99999999))`, I get error that `week` column doesn't exist. I think because that is temporary column?

So my question is, how to properly sort by temporary week column or is there a better way to sort it?:)

Comment: write it as a sub select or include the case to evaluate week in the order by

Comment: @Tatsuo: Formatting text blocks, like table samples or code snippets, is easy: just indent every line with at least 4 spaces. Add more spaces to introduce indentation *within* the block, as necessary. Add at least one empty line before the block to divide it from the previous paragraph.

Comment: @xQbert if I try to use week column in CASE, I get error, that column doesn't exist as it is temporary column. Same problem as trying to use to_number(week, text(99999999)

Comment: Since I can't test the options I wanted to present, I'll stick with either wrapping your logic in a sub select or include the case statement instead of week.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id) AS id,
  week || ' ' || year AS week,
  year,
  COUNT(*) AS amount,
  SUM(price_unit) AS price
FROM (
  SELECT
    so.id,
    DATE_PART('week',  so.date_order) AS week,
    DATE_PART('year',  so.date_order) AS year,
    sol.price_unit
  FROM sale_order AS so
    INNER JOIN sale_order_line AS sol ON sol.order_id = so.id
  WHERE so.date_order BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
) AS x
GROUP BY
  year,
  week
ORDER BY
  week::int,
  year
```

Comment: Thanks, it sorts as I want to, but somehow if I use this sql, I can't get graph from it.. Just get white window.. And if I change x value from week to year, I can get graph, but I need with weeks. Don't get it what's the problem with it. Also in line where is INNER JOIN, it should be sale_order_line as sol, not sale_order as sol :)

Comment: Fixed the `sale_order_line` bit. On the other point, I'm not sure about what could be wrong. The `week` column in the result set is a string – does the graph work correctly with string columns as X values? I mean, does it work correctly when the string values are arbitrary, not just numbers converted to strings?

Comment: A quick suggestion: try `week || '.' || year` instead of `week || ' ' || year` and see if it works. (It might display `1.2010` as `1.201`, though, if my suspicions are correct.)

Comment: Thanks again, it worked. I tried with ' - ', but their were spaces, so I suppose their can't be spaces. So I stayed with '-', because with '.' somehow eats 0 from year 2010 in graph. EDIT: Damn.. didn't see that now it sorts old way.. So I got back where I started..

Comment: But thats maybe graph thing, because in query I see it sorted in way I want, but when I open graph, it somehow resorts in '1 2010' 1 '2011' 10 '2010' 10 '2011' way.